# removing old BTRFS snapshots with bash

Tags: linux, bash, backup, bash-scripting, btrfs

I'm trying to build my own little backup script, I want to use BTRFS snapshots and keep them for a while. Meanwhile, creating the snapshots is no longer a problem for me, but now I would like to delete them again after 5 days.

I have worked out the following command to get the creation time of the snapshots.

```
/usr/bin/find /run/btrfs-root/sdb/__snapshot/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name "auto-sn-*" -exec /usr/sbin/btrfs subvolume show {} \; | /usr/bin/grep "__snapshot|Creation"
```

output:

```
__snapshot/auto-sn-data-20210803
        Creation time:          2021-08-03 14:59:01 +0200
__snapshot/auto-sn-Log-20210803
        Creation time:          2021-08-03 15:00:42 +0200
```

Unfortunately, I can't find a way to make a deletion decision based on the output date string.
Now the exact question is, how can I initiate a deletion of the snapshot after 5 days based on this information?

Thank you

**Small idea:**

```
/usr/bin/find /run/btrfs-root/sdb/__snapshot/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name "auto-sn-*" ! \( -name "*$(/usr/bin/date -d '1 day ago' +%Y%m%d)" -o -name "*$(/usr/bin/date -d '2 day ago' +%Y%m%d)"  -o -name "*$(/usr/bin/date -d '3 day ago' +%Y%m%d)" \) -exec /usr/sbin/btrfs subvolume delete {} \;
```

I do not know if this would work

Comment: (1) Is your intention to rely on strings like `2021-08-03 14:59:01 +0200` from the output of `btrfs subvolume show`? or on substrings like `20210803` from filenames? (2) Aren't you reinventing `snapper`? (and `snapper-cleanup.timer`, `snapper-cleanup.service`).

Comment: 1: my trust would go more into the btrfs output and not on the name. 
2: sadly yes @KamilMaciorowski

Answer (score 0):

To get just the date, you can do this:

```
$ btrfs subvolume show / | grep -oP 'Creation time:\s*\K\d.*$'
# 2021-03-11 04:22:58 +0100
```

You're basically done at this point because thankfully, the dates are in ISO format which you can trivially compare using normal bash string comparison functions:

```
$ old_date=$(btrfs subvolume show / | grep -oP 'Creation time:\s*\K\d.*$')
(some time passes)
$ new_date=$(btrfs subvolume show / | grep -oP 'Creation time:\s*\K\d.*$')
$ [[ "$old_date" < "$new_date" ]] && echo newer || echo older
```